# Not able to start Infinispan server

Tags: java, caching, infinispan

I am trying to start Infinispan server in my Ubuntu machine. Below is my machine-

> rkost@rj-vm9-14105:~/infinispan/infinispan-server-6.0.0.Alpha1/bin$
> uname -a
>
> Linux rj-vm9-14105 2.6.35-22-server #33-Ubuntu SMP Sun Sep 19
> 20:48:58 UTC 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I was going through this [article](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ISPN/Infinispan+Server)  and I downloaded Infinispan Server distribution (Infinispan servers (HotRod, REST, Memcached)) from this [link](http://www.jboss.org/infinispan/downloads). After downloading it, I started running it from my Ubuntu machine like this-

**Update:-**

```
root@rj-vm9-14105:/home/rkost/infinispan/infinispan-server-6.0.0.Alpha1/bin# sh standalone.sh
=========================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: /home/rkost/infinispan/infinispan-server-6.0.0.Alpha1

  JAVA: java

  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -XX:+UseCompressedOops -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true

=========================================================================

18:11:23,417 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.2.0.CR1
18:11:23,748 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.0.4.GA
18:11:23,851 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015899: JBoss Infinispan Server 6.0.0.Alpha1 (AS 7.2.0.Final) starting
18:11:24,998 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-1) XNIO Version 3.0.7.GA
18:11:25,003 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-1) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.7.GA
18:11:25,010 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
18:11:25,020 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBoss Remoting version 3.2.14.GA
18:11:25,097 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 21) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
18:11:25,116 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 17) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
18:11:25,143 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.logging] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.15.Final)
18:11:25,144 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 23) JBAS013171: Activating Security Subsystem
18:11:25,386 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS012605: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main, 1.2]
18:11:25,408 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
18:11:25,413 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS013170: Current PicketBox version=4.0.15.Final
18:11:26,025 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.ajp] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBWEB003046: Starting Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-/127.0.0.1:8009
18:11:26,030 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBWEB003001: Coyote HTTP/1.1 initializing on : http-/127.0.0.1:8080
18:11:26,064 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBWEB003000: Coyote HTTP/1.1 starting on: http-/127.0.0.1:8080
18:11:26,594 INFO  [org.infinispan.server.endpoint] (MSC service thread 1-1) JDGS010000: HotRodServer starting
18:11:26,596 INFO  [org.infinispan.server.endpoint] (MSC service thread 1-1) JDGS010001: HotRodServer listening on 127.0.0.1:11222
18:11:26,686 INFO  [org.infinispan.server.endpoint] (MSC service thread 1-2) JDGS010000: WebSocketServer starting
18:11:26,686 INFO  [org.infinispan.server.endpoint] (MSC service thread 1-2) JDGS010001: WebSocketServer listening on 127.0.0.1:8181
18:11:27,223 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-1) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan '<TBD>' 6.0.0.Alpha1
18:11:27,883 INFO  [org.infinispan.jmx.CacheJmxRegistration] (MSC service thread 1-1) ISPN000031: MBeans were successfully registered to the platform MBean server.
18:11:27,892 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS010281: Started default cache from local container
18:11:28,165 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.endpoint.websocket.websocket-connector: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.endpoint.websocket.websocket-connector: JDGS010004: Failed to start WebSocketServer
        at org.infinispan.server.endpoint.subsystem.ProtocolServerService.start(ProtocolServerService.java:106)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA.jar:1.0.4.GA]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA.jar:1.0.4.GA]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
Caused by: org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to create a selector.
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.openSelector(AbstractNioSelector.java:337)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.<init>(AbstractNioSelector.java:95)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.<init>(AbstractNioWorker.java:51)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.<init>(NioWorker.java:45)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorkerPool.createWorker(NioWorkerPool.java:45)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorkerPool.createWorker(NioWorkerPool.java:28)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorkerPool.newWorker(AbstractNioWorkerPool.java:99)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorkerPool.init(AbstractNioWorkerPool.java:69)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorkerPool.<init>(NioWorkerPool.java:39)
        at org.infinispan.server.core.transport.NettyTransport.<init>(NettyTransport.scala:51)
        at org.infinispan.server.core.AbstractProtocolServer.startTransport(AbstractProtocolServer.scala:44)
        at org.infinispan.server.core.AbstractProtocolServer.start(AbstractProtocolServer.scala:39)
        at org.infinispan.server.websocket.WebSocketServer.start(WebSocketServer.java:63)
        at org.infinispan.server.endpoint.subsystem.ProtocolServerService.startProtocolServer(ProtocolServerService.java:123)
        at org.infinispan.server.endpoint.subsystem.ProtocolServerService.start(ProtocolServerService.java:100)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Too many open files
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollCreate(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.<init>(EPollArrayWrapper.java:87) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.<init>(EPollSelectorImpl.java:70) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorProvider.openSelector(EPollSelectorProvider.java:36) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
        at java.nio.channels.Selector.open(Selector.java:226) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.openSelector(AbstractNioSelector.java:335)
        ... 19 more

18:11:28,181 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.endpoint.hotrod.hotrod-connector: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.endpoint.hotrod.hotrod-connector: JDGS010004: Failed to start HotRodServer
        at org.infinispan.server.endpoint.subsystem.ProtocolServerService.start(ProtocolServerService.java:106)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA.jar:1.0.4.GA]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA.jar:1.0.4.GA]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
Caused by: org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to open a server socket.
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.<init>(NioServerSocketChannel.java:57)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannelFactory.newChannel(NioServerSocketChannelFactory.java:205)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannelFactory.newChannel(NioServerSocketChannelFactory.java:85)
        at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap.bindAsync(ServerBootstrap.java:329)
        at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap.bind(ServerBootstrap.java:266)
        at org.infinispan.server.core.transport.NettyTransport.start(NettyTransport.scala:83)
        at org.infinispan.server.core.AbstractProtocolServer.startTransport(AbstractProtocolServer.scala:49)
        at org.infinispan.server.hotrod.HotRodServer.startTransport(HotRodServer.scala:67)
        at org.infinispan.server.core.AbstractProtocolServer.start(AbstractProtocolServer.scala:39)
        at org.infinispan.server.hotrod.HotRodServer.start(HotRodServer.scala:51)
        at org.infinispan.server.hotrod.HotRodServer.start(HotRodServer.scala:27)
        at org.infinispan.server.endpoint.subsystem.ProtocolServerService.startProtocolServer(ProtocolServerService.java:123)
        at org.infinispan.server.endpoint.subsystem.ProtocolServerService.start(ProtocolServerService.java:100)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Too many open files
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.socket0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.serverSocket(Net.java:119) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.<init>(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:91) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorProviderImpl.openServerSocketChannel(SelectorProviderImpl.java:51) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
        at java.nio.channels.ServerSocketChannel.open(ServerSocketChannel.java:92) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.<init>(NioServerSocketChannel.java:55)
        ... 17 more

18:11:28,252 INFO  [org.infinispan.jmx.CacheJmxRegistration] (MSC service thread 1-1) ISPN000031: MBeans were successfully registered to the platform MBean server.
18:11:28,251 INFO  [org.infinispan.jmx.CacheJmxRegistration] (MSC service thread 1-2) ISPN000031: MBeans were successfully registered to the platform MBean server.
18:11:28,256 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS010281: Started other cache from security container
18:11:28,263 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010281: Started jboss-web-policy cache from security container
18:11:28,267 INFO  [org.infinispan.jmx.CacheJmxRegistration] (MSC service thread 1-2) ISPN000031: MBeans were successfully registered to the platform MBean server.
18:11:28,268 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010281: Started memcachedCache cache from local container
18:11:28,271 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.server.controller.management.security_realm.ManagementRealm.properties_authentication: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.server.controller.management.security_realm.ManagementRealm.properties_authentication: JBAS015228: Unable to load properties
        at org.jboss.as.domain.management.security.PropertiesFileLoader.start(PropertiesFileLoader.java:81)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA.jar:1.0.4.GA]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA.jar:1.0.4.GA]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/rkost/infinispan/infinispan-server-6.0.0.Alpha1/standalone/configuration/mgmt-users.properties (Too many open files)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:137) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
        at org.jboss.as.domain.management.security.PropertiesFileLoader.getProperties(PropertiesFileLoader.java:108)
        at org.jboss.as.domain.management.security.PropertiesFileLoader.start(PropertiesFileLoader.java:79)
        ... 5 more

18:11:28,272 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.server.controller.management.security_realm.ApplicationRealm.properties_authentication: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.server.controller.management.security_realm.ApplicationRealm.properties_authentication: JBAS015228: Unable to load properties
        at org.jboss.as.domain.management.security.PropertiesFileLoader.start(PropertiesFileLoader.java:81)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA.jar:1.0.4.GA]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA.jar:1.0.4.GA]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/rkost/infinispan/infinispan-server-6.0.0.Alpha1/standalone/configuration/application-users.properties (Too many open files)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:137) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
        at org.jboss.as.domain.management.security.PropertiesFileLoader.getProperties(PropertiesFileLoader.java:108)
        at org.jboss.as.domain.management.security.PropertiesFileLoader.start(PropertiesFileLoader.java:79)
        ... 5 more

18:11:28,284 INFO  [org.infinispan.jmx.CacheJmxRegistration] (MSC service thread 1-1) ISPN000031: MBeans were successfully registered to the platform MBean server.
18:11:28,284 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS010281: Started namedCache cache from local container
18:11:28,285 INFO  [org.infinispan.server.endpoint] (MSC service thread 1-1) JDGS010000: REST starting
18:11:28,287 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-1) ZoneInfo: /usr/share/javazi/ZoneInfoMappings (Too many open files)
18:11:28,289 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-1) Failed to define class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap in Module "org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs:main" from local module loader @19e3118a (finder: local module finder @a94884d (roots: /home/rkost/infinispan/infinispan-server-6.0.0.Alpha1/modules,/home/rkost/infinispan/infinispan-server-6.0.0.Alpha1/modules/system/layers/base)): org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoadError: No module.xml file found at /home/rkost/infinispan/infinispan-server-6.0.0.Alpha1/modules/system/layers/base/org/apache/commons/codec/main/module.xml
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoadException.toError(ModuleLoadException.java:78) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.getPathsUnchecked(Module.java:1180) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:513) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:182) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:338) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:402) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:254) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:73) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:518) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:182) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
        at org.infinispan.server.endpoint.subsystem.RestService.start(RestService.java:133) [infinispan-server-endpoints-6.0.0.Alpha1.jar:6.0.0.Alpha1]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA.jar:1.0.4.GA]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA.jar:1.0.4.GA]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]

18:11:28,291 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.endpoint.rest.rest-connector: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.endpoint.rest.rest-connector: Failed to start service
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1767) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA.jar:1.0.4.GA]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/resteasy/plugins/server/servlet/ResteasyBootstrap
        at org.infinispan.server.endpoint.subsystem.RestService.start(RestService.java:133)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA.jar:1.0.4.GA]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA.jar:1.0.4.GA]
        ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap from [Module "org.infinispan.server.endpoint:main" from local module loader @19e3118a (finder: local module finder @a94884d (roots: /home/rkost/infinispan/infinispan-server-6.0.0.Alpha1/modules,/home/rkost/infinispan/infinispan-server-6.0.0.Alpha1/modules/system/layers/base))]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
        ... 6 more

18:11:28,293 INFO  [org.infinispan.server.endpoint] (MSC service thread 1-2) JDGS010000: MemcachedServer starting
18:11:28,294 INFO  [org.infinispan.server.endpoint] (MSC service thread 1-2) JDGS010001: MemcachedServer listening on 127.0.0.1:11211
18:11:28,295 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.endpoint.memcached.memcached-connector: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.endpoint.memcached.memcached-connector: JDGS010004: Failed to start MemcachedServer
        at org.infinispan.server.endpoint.subsystem.ProtocolServerService.start(ProtocolServerService.java:106)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA.jar:1.0.4.GA]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA.jar:1.0.4.GA]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
Caused by: org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to create a selector.
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.openSelector(AbstractNioSelector.java:337)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.<init>(AbstractNioSelector.java:95)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerBoss.<init>(NioServerBoss.java:49)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerBossPool.newBoss(NioServerBossPool.java:55)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerBossPool.newBoss(NioServerBossPool.java:26)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioBossPool.init(AbstractNioBossPool.java:65)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerBossPool.<init>(NioServerBossPool.java:40)
        at org.infinispan.server.core.transport.NettyTransport.<init>(NettyTransport.scala:39)
        at org.infinispan.server.core.AbstractProtocolServer.startTransport(AbstractProtocolServer.scala:44)
        at org.infinispan.server.core.AbstractProtocolServer.start(AbstractProtocolServer.scala:39)
        at org.infinispan.server.memcached.MemcachedServer.start(MemcachedServer.scala:30)
        at org.infinispan.server.memcached.MemcachedServer.start(MemcachedServer.scala:17)
        at org.infinispan.server.endpoint.subsystem.ProtocolServerService.startProtocolServer(ProtocolServerService.java:123)
        at org.infinispan.server.endpoint.subsystem.ProtocolServerService.start(ProtocolServerService.java:100)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Too many open files
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.initPipe(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.<init>(EPollSelectorImpl.java:67) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorProvider.openSelector(EPollSelectorProvider.java:36) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
        at java.nio.channels.Selector.open(Selector.java:226) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.openSelector(AbstractNioSelector.java:335)
        ... 18 more

18:11:28,935 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.client] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014781: Step handler org.jboss.as.logging.LoggingOperations$CommitOperationStepHandler@3c9076d for operation add at address [("subsystem" => "logging")] failed handling operation rollback -- JBAS011565: Failed to write configuration file /home/rkost/infinispan/infinispan-server-6.0.0.Alpha1/standalone/configuration/logging.properties
18:11:28,937 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.endpoint.rest.rest-connector: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.endpoint.rest.rest-connector: Failed to start service
      service jboss.server.controller.management.security_realm.ManagementRealm.properties_authentication: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.server.controller.management.security_realm.ManagementRealm.properties_authentication: JBAS015228: Unable to load properties
      service jboss.endpoint.memcached.memcached-connector: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.endpoint.memcached.memcached-connector: JDGS010004: Failed to start MemcachedServer
      service jboss.endpoint.hotrod.hotrod-connector: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.endpoint.hotrod.hotrod-connector: JDGS010004: Failed to start HotRodServer
      service jboss.endpoint.websocket.websocket-connector: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.endpoint.websocket.websocket-connector: JDGS010004: Failed to start WebSocketServer
      service jboss.server.controller.management.security_realm.ApplicationRealm.properties_authentication: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.server.controller.management.security_realm.ApplicationRealm.properties_authentication: JBAS015228: Unable to load properties

18:11:28,945 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015956: Caught exception during boot: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationFile.createHistoryDirectory(ConfigurationFile.java:482) [jboss-as-controller-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationFile.successfulBoot(ConfigurationFile.java:306) [jboss-as-controller-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.BackupXmlConfigurationPersister.successfulBoot(BackupXmlConfigurationPersister.java:65) [jboss-as-controller-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.finishBoot(AbstractControllerService.java:234) [jboss-as-controller-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:310) [jboss-as-server-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:188) [jboss-as-controller-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]

18:11:28,945 FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015957: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.
18:11:28,959 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS014774: Service status report
```

Does anyone know why I am getting the exception? And what I should do to fix the problem? I have spend whole one day to figure this thing out.

Comment: Hi, I've downloaded it too to try things out. For my Fedora16 everything is starting fine. Please, check your /etc/security/limits.conf and take a look here: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ISPN/Contributing+-+The+test+suite on the options from rhusar. Try to reset it accordingly and let us know whether this solved your problem. It has to definitely be something environment related because on my machine server is running without any problems.

Comment: I added those lines in that file but still I am getting the exception. I am pretty much sure, it is environment specific and I am not sure what should I do to fix those.. Updated my question with the exception details again.

Comment: I'm leaving for a vacation... I suggest you to join infinispan-dev mailing list or #infinispan channel on freenode IRC and ask there. I hope developers will help you ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw you already got it work. (https://community.jboss.org/message/828728)

It didn't work for you after changing /etc/security/limits.conf numbers because changes in this file are applied after re-login.

For other people with this problem, please, see https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ISPN/Contributing+-+The+test+suite, set your limits accordingly and re-login.

Check your limits using

```
ulimit -a
```

Comment: This thing is fixed. Now the only problem that I am facing is I am not able to form a cluster of two nodes. Here is the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17753107/not-able-to-form-a-cluster-of-two-nodes-using-infinispan-server) for that as well. Any help will be appreciated on that.