# 6.0.0.CR1 infinispan server cluster not forming when launched from different machine

Tags: java, caching, memcached, infinispan

i downloaded 6.0.0.CR1 server installation and launched 2 instances using cluster.bat on my machine with all default configurations and i  see that the cluster is formed but when i launch another instance on a different machine in the same network it does not add to the cluster . is there anything i need to change in the cluster.xml to allow that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure as I can't see any server logs. However, it looks like you are (of course) using default configuration which bounds nodes to 127.0.0.1 for searching other nodes. Therefore, you are not able to see nodes on other machines.

Please, see this question+answer and try suggested solution by Galder and I hope that will help you.

[Not able to form a cluster of two nodes using Infinispan server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17753107/not-able-to-form-a-cluster-of-two-nodes-using-infinispan-server)

Comment: Hi tsykora thanks for the Help. Do you know of any good document i can refer to for Infinispan server setup the UserGuide looks bit outdated

Comment: Hi, no problem at all. I'm glad that it was helpful :) If you are referring to http://infinispan.org/docs/6.0.x/user_guide/user_guide.html and this is outdated, feel free to file JIRA (bug) (https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ISPN) and developers will improve it. I think there are no other documents and doc itself should be reliable source of information like this. It's impossible to be ok with: "just ask for more updated doc" approach :) Thank you

Comment: Hi tsykora based on galder post which one would be NIC address:Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : 
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.30.58.9
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.254.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.30.58.1  I tried the subnetmask and defautl gateway and

Comment: i am getting:   10:43:06,598 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
10:43:07,075 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-8) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.network.public: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.network.public: JBAS015810: failed to resolve interface public
        at

Comment: at org.jboss.as.server.services.net.NetworkInterfaceService.start(NetworkInterfaceService.java:97) [jboss-as-server-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
 at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA.jar:1.0.4.GA]
 at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA.jar:1.0.4.GA]
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_34]
 at

Comment: Unfortunately, I've never met your issue. But, I've found this thread which is maybe worth to look at: https://community.jboss.org/thread/222677

Comment: Hi tsykora can you put some light on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19670244/infinispan-clustering-applications-on-2-servers